# Query table to show the max date in Kusto KQL Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How would be a query in Kusto in order to query various fields, by filtering the data for its max date column only. ex: see only on the query data for 09-08-2023

something like |where datecolumn == max(datecolumn)

example:

```
Animals   Color      Datecolumn
cat        orange     01-08-2023
dog        black      03-08-2023
bird       yellow     09-08-2023
dog        white      09-08-2023
```

I want to return all the columns and field selected and only filter the data by its max(date) which in this case is for now 09-08-2023 (2 rows in the example), but overall for the future I want the max/lates datecolumn value always.

In the practice I'm querying more columns and doing some extend functions in my query but I just want to filter the data by its latest date always

Comment: What do you want, can you provide, input and output

Comment: @RithwikBojja I edited my question, is a quite basic question, but I'm not used to Kusto so not sure what's the right query to get the data filtered by the latest date available in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
let Table1 = datatable(Animals:string, Color:string, Datecolumn:datetime)
[
'cat', 'orange', datetime(2023-08-01),
'dog', 'black', datetime(2023-08-03),
'bird', 'yellow', datetime(2023-08-09),
'dog', 'white', datetime(2023-08-09)
];
let max_date = toscalar(Table1| summarize MaxDate = max(Datecolumn));
Table1
| where Datecolumn == max_date
```

The query first create a scalar value called  `max_date`  using the  `let`  statement and the  `toscalar`  function. The  `toscalar`  function returns a single scalar value from a table, which in this case is the maximum date value from the  `Datecolumn`  field in  `Table1`. Then the query filters the data in  `Table1`  by the maximum date value using the where Datecolumn matches with `max_date`  value.

**Output:**

| Animals | Color | Datecolumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bird | yellow | 2023-08-09T00:00:00Z |
| dog | white | 2023-08-09T00:00:00Z |